# Append to target link libraries

Tags: cmake

Currently, in my CMake file, I do the following based on whether OpenMP is found or not:

```
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE lib_1 lib_2 OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX PUBLIC io_lib)
else(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE lib_1 lib_2 PUBLIC io_lib)
```

Perhaps, I am being picky here but this looks a bit ugly. I am wondering if there is a canonical way to do this which does not result in an ugly config. Perhaps, something like appending to the list of libs might be cleaner, but I could not figure out how to access the `PRIVATE` interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A couple variations:*

Instead, you can just conditionally append the `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX` target:

```
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE lib_1 lib_2 PUBLIC io_lib)
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
endif()
```

as consecutive calls to [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) for the same target will **append** items in the order called.

Or, you can cut this logic down to a one-liner, using a [conditional generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#conditional-expressions):

```
target_link_libraries(myapp 
    PRIVATE lib_1 lib_2 $<IF:${OpenMP_CXX_FOUND},OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX,> 
    PUBLIC io_lib
)
```

Comment: Oh wow...I did not know that this conditional stuff worked like that. Thanks. The one-liner would make someone hate me, so I will skip it :D

Comment: @Luca Yes, consecutive calls to the same target will **append** items in the order called. And agreed, generator expressions can be ugly, and sometimes make it *less* clear what is going on. :)